# Gamekit / gamecenter random matchmaking programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, gamekit

I am trying to implement random matchmaking programmatically with my own custom userinterface.

I'm kinda stuck..

using this code found at the apple site I can create a match without problems

```
- (void)findProgrammaticMatch
{
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];

    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;


    [GKTurnBasedMatch findMatchForRequest: request withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error)
     {
         if(error)
             NSLog(@"ERROR");
         if (match) {

             NSLog(@"STARTING MATCH");
         }

     }];
}
```

and if I do match.participants.count I get the number 2...

but one participant is me and the other is null

What ive done to test is create 2 sandbox accounts and I ran the same code with my other game center account, and I got a new game created,.. but it didnt match them for some reason.. am I missing something?

ive been looking for examples on google, but I can't seem to find any.. if any of you know anywhere I can find some examples, I would be most grateful

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might be missing out an essential point in turn based match making. When the user starts an automatch if he is not connected to an existing match it starts a fresh game and user takes the first turn. Only after HE COMPLETES HIS TURN, other users can connect to this game. So if you are making a 2 player match: one user should start a fresh game with the other user being null at that moment and the other user should connect to this existing game after the first one finished his turn (endTurnWithMatchData called)

This is not very clear in documentation (I despise the gamecenter documentation, unclear & incomplete) but it is the case for sdk 6. I think it will change in the near future.